# How to pass Firebase data in RecyclerView to second Activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

> ### Second Activity
>
> class BookDescription : AppCompatActivity() {
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_description)
>
> ```
>     var books = intent.getParcelableExtra("String") as Book
>     Glide.with(this).load(books.imageUrl).into(bookImg1)
>     nameTxt1.text = books.name
>     autorTxt1.text = books.name
> } }
> ```
>
> ### Adapter class
>
> class Adapter(private val context: Context) :
> RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder>() {
>
> ```
> private var datalist = mutableListOf<Book>()
> fun setListdata(data: MutableList<Book>){
>     datalist = data
> }
>
> inner class Holder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
>      fun bindView(book: Book){
>          Glide.with(context).load(book.imageUrl).into(itemView.bookImg)
>          itemView.nameTxt.text = book.name
>          itemView.autorTxt.text= book.writer
>
>          itemView.bookImg.setOnClickListener(
>                  View.OnClickListener {
>                      val intent = Intent(context, BookDescription::class.java)
>                      intent.putExtra("jbg", book)
>                      context.startActivity(intent)
>                  }
>          )
>      }
> }
>
> override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
>     val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.book_format, parent,
> ```
>
> false )
> return Holder(view)
> }
>
> ```
> override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
>        val book = datalist[position]
>        holder.bindView(book)
> }
>
> override fun getItemCount(): Int {
>    return if (datalist.size> 0){
>         datalist.size
>     }else{
>         0
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> ### Main Activity
>
> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
>
> ```
> private lateinit var adapter : Adapter
> private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)}
>
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
>
>     adapter = Adapter(this)
>     recycle.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
>     recycle.adapter = adapter
>     observerData()
> }
>
>    fun observerData(){
>        viewModel.fetchUserData().observe(this,Observer{
>            adapter.setListdata(it)
>            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
>        })
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ### Class Book
>
> @Parcelize data class Book(val imageUrl:String= "URL IMmage",
> val name:String = "Naziv knjige",
> val writer:String= "Pisac knjige") :Parcelable!
>
> - *[Logcat]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnt2O.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your `Book` class implements [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable), and then make sure that the key used to put the extra matches the key used to retrieve it:

#### Adapter

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(context, BookDescription::class.java)
intent.putParcelable("UNIQUE_KEY", book)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

#### BookDescription

```kotlin
var books = intent.getParcelableExtra("UNIQUE_KEY") as Book
```

Comment: Done but still no data is transferred, the application crashes. @Ryan

Comment: could you provide a crash log?

Comment: A photo (logcat) is inserted. The application crashes the moment you click on recyclerView to switch to another activity.@Ryan

Comment: are you sure that inside the `onClickListener` the `book` is not `null`?

Comment: Yes, I put a breaking point and everything is fine until I start creating intent for a new activity. @Ryan

Comment: sorry man not sure what else i can tell you. your stacktrace says that it cannot cast null to non-null, meaning the book you are placing inside the intent seems to be null. perhaps it is an issue with whichever library you are using to implement parcelable with the @Parcelize annotation - perhaps try implementing it yourself. Android Studio provides the tooling to autofill the implementation, just mark the class Book as implementing parcelable and Android Studio should recommend the implementation